# Using database into Swipe view

Tags: android, sql, swipeview

I am a beginner in Android and I would like to use my data base to print names from it into swipe views. I downloaded the example project from Android developer web site (http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html). I have tried to change the code using AsyncTask to call the data base, but I did not succeed. Do you have any idea how to do this ?
The main problem I have is that makehttprequest does not work inside my fragment (into the doinbackground from asynctask)

```
public class DemoObjectFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";
    private static final String url ="http://www.golinkr.net";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PROFILE_INFO = "Profile_Info";
    private static final String TAG_FIRST_NAME = "First_Name";
    private static final String SELECT_FUNCTION = "getProfile";
    private static final String ID = "2";


    JSONArray profileInfos = null;
    HashMap<String,String> profile;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_collection_object, container, false);
        profile = new HashMap<String, String>();
        bindGridview();
        return rootView;
    }

    public void bindGridview(){
        new MyAsyncTask(getActivity()).execute("");
    }

    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        Activity mContex;

        public MyAsyncTask(Activity contex) {
            this.mContex=contex;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SELECT_FUNCTION",SELECT_FUNCTION));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ID", ID));
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url,"POST",params);

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = json.toString();
            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            //if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success==1){
                    profileInfos=json.getJSONArray(TAG_PROFILE_INFO);
                    for (int i = 0; i<profileInfos.length();i++){
                        JSONObject c = profileInfos.getJSONObject(i);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_FIRST_NAME)

                        profile.put(TAG_NAME,name);

                    }
                }
                else{
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DemoObjectFragment.class);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            TextView txt = (TextView) mContex.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            txt.setText("Bonjour");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thanks in advance.
Sorry if the question looks similar to previous questions

Comment: Your question will be closed very quickly if you do not provide more information.  `but I did not succeed` - show the code please, exactly what problem did you have?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried to give more details.

Comment: "does not work".  Your app crashes?  It shows the wrong result?  You get nothing?  Your dog died?  The sun stopped shining?

Comment: My app crashes (it shuts down on my phone when my activity starts). With the logcat, I can see that the mistake appears after this line :JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url,"POST",params);  The errors I got does not refer to the current activity, but to core  files.

Comment: @user3300795 That the root of the traceback does not point to your files is not a certain indication that you are not doing anything wrong. Most likely you are passing invalid arguments to ``makeHttpRequest``.

Comment: @JonasWielicki: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I have exactly the same code in an activity and I get back the data from my database with no problem. This is why I guess the error must be linked to the fragment architecture ?